# shopify is not a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

## I am having a Shopify plugin which gave me an error of shopify is not a class

Model name: Class Shopify

embeded_one: shopify

webhooks jobs class name: class Shopify

I am using shopify app gem for building a shopify a plugin. also, I am using rails 5.1 and mongoid 7.0

```rb
class Shopify::Webhooks::ProductsUpdateJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    # Do something later
    puts("Product Updated Job called...!!")
    user = User.find_by({"shopify.domain": domain})
    # perform weebhooks
```

problem is I have the same project structure for my other Shopify app but it's run and build successfully in production.

Comment: Well, clearly not everything is the same. Otherwise it would have worked here too. Compare the two projects and find material differences.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Shopify::Webhooks::ProductsUpdateJob` is being evaluated before `Shopify` is defined.

Try this:

```
module Shopify
  module Webhooks
    class ProductsUpdateJob < ApplicationJob
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

(Also, I wouldn't recommend naming your own module `Shopify` at top level, being a third-party platform.)